# Plot feature importance with xgboost

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, xgboost, feature-selection

When I plot the feature importance, I get this messy plot. I have more than 7000 variables. I understand the built-in function only selects the most important, although the final graph is unreadable. 
This is the complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('ricerice.csv')
array=df.values
X = array[:,0:7803]
Y = array[:,7804]
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
seed=0
test_size=0.30
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=test_size, random_state=seed)
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X, Y)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot
from xgboost import plot_importance
fig1=plt.gcf()
plot_importance(model)
plt.draw()
fig1.savefig('xgboost.png', figsize=(50, 40), dpi=1000)
```

Although the size of the figure, the graph is illegible. [image: xgboost feature importance plot]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are couple of points:

1. To fit the model, you want to use the training dataset (`X_train, y_train`), not the entire dataset (`X, y`).
2. You may use the `max_num_features` parameter of the `plot_importance()` function to display only top `max_num_features` features (e.g. top 10).

With the above modifications to your code, with some randomly generated data the code and output are as below:

```
import numpy as np

# generate some random data for demonstration purpose, use your original dataset here
X = np.random.rand(1000,100)     # 1000 x 100 data
y = np.random.rand(1000).round() # 0, 1 labels

from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
seed=0
test_size=0.30
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=test_size, random_state=seed)
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot
from xgboost import plot_importance
plot_importance(model, max_num_features=10) # top 10 most important features
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: how do i get what f39 is?

Comment: use `model.get_booster().get_score(importance_type='weight')` to get importance of all features.

Comment: if you're using **make_pipeline** to instantiate your model, then you can use the following to assign feature names: `xg_boost.get_booster().feature_names = list(ml_pipeline[0].get_feature_names_out())`

Answer (score 4):

You need to sort your feature importances in descending order first:

```
sorted_idx = trained_mdl.feature_importances_.argsort()[::-1]
```

Then just plot them with the column names from your dataframe

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
n_top_features = 10
sorted_idx = trained_mdl.feature_importances_.argsort()[::-1]
plt.barh(X_test.columns[sorted_idx][:n_top_features ], trained_mdl.feature_importances_[sorted_idx][:n_top_features ])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain feature importance from Xgboost model with `feature_importances_` attribute. In your case, it will be:

```py
model.feature_imortances_
```

This attribute is the array with `gain` importance for each feature. Then you can plot it:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.barh(feature_names, model.feature_importances_)
```

(`feature_names` is a list with features names)

You can sort the array and select the number of features you want (for example, 10):

```py
sorted_idx = model.feature_importances_.argsort()
plt.barh(feature_names[sorted_idx][:10], model.feature_importances_[sorted_idx][:10])
plt.xlabel("Xgboost Feature Importance")
```

There are two more methods to get feature importance:

- you can use `permutation_importance` from `scikit-learn` (from version 0.22)
- you can use SHAP values

You can read more in this [blog post](https://mljar.com/blog/feature-importance-xgboost/) of mine.

Comment: you need to sort descending order to make this work correctly.